# Infinite Loop While Reading and Writing from Files - C

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to read from an input file and ultimately reverse the buffer it reads from and write it to an output file. For now though, I'm testing to see if a buffer I read from would even make it to the output file, and so far it isn't and I'm getting an infinite loop. The buffer should read in PAGESIZE bytes (from a call to sysconf()) and if the file output is larger than the buffer, then the buffer should be written to the output file first then be flushed and reused again to get the rest of the input until the file descriptor returns 0 for no data left. This is what I have so far:

```
int fdRead = open(inputFile, O_RDONLY);
if (fdRead == -1)
    err_sys("Error reading input file '%s', check spelling?\n", inputFile);
int fdWrite = open(outputFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644); //overwrites file if it exists
if (fdWrite == -1)
    err_sys("Error creating output file '%s'\n", outputFile);
while (1) {
    read(fdRead, buf, size);
    if (fdRead == 0)
        break;
    if (fdRead == -1)
        err_sys("Error reading from input file '%s'\n", inputFile);
    lseek(fdRead, size, SEEK_CUR);
    if (fdRead == -1)
        err_sys("Error reading from input file '%s'\n", inputFile);
    write(fdWrite, buf, size);
    if (fdWrite == -1)
        err_sys("Error writing to output file '%s'\n", outputFile);
    lseek(fdWrite, size, SEEK_CUR);
    if (fdWrite == -1)
        err_sys("Error writing to output file '%s'\n", outputFile);
    memset(buf, '\0', size);
}
close(fdRead);
close(fdWrite);
```

I suppose that fdRead is never returning 0, and thus not exiting the loop. My question is how do I fix that?

p.s: size is the call from sysconf() that gets the PAGESIZE, e.g

```
size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
```

And inputFile and outputFile are both char * and I've tested that they return and store good strings.

Comment: You need to capture the return value from `read()` — you're ignoring it and testing whether the file descriptor is 0 after the `read()`.  You need: `int nbytes = read(fdRead, buf, size);` and `if (nbytes <= 0) break;`.  You should use the positive `nbytes` in the ``write()`` call; you might not get all `size` bytes filled by the `read()`.

Comment: So if I did something like int bytesRead then tested for if (bytesRead == 0) instead of if (fdRead == 0), then that should solve my problem?

Comment: Basically, yes — that's what my extended comment suggests (extended while you were typing your comment/question).  There could be other issues; I've not scrutinized the code.  But testing the file descriptor after the read is wrong (it won't have changed under normal circumstances), and ignoring the value returned by `read()` is wrong, and not using the value returned by `read()` in the call to `write()` is wrong.

Comment: OK so it should be write(fdWrite, buf, nbytes)?

Comment: Yes, it should be `if (write(fdWrite, buf, nbytes) != nbytes) …oops — short write …`.  You get to decide what's the appropriate response to a short write.  If you're writing to a socket, it might be appropriate to try writing the unwritten section of the data again.  If you're writing to a disk file, it probably means there's no space left, so there's no point (little point) in trying again.

Comment: Also you have to avoid executing your `while (1)` in case the failure of `open` of `inputFile` and `outputFile` by `exit`ing for example.

Comment: Okay, this all has helped out a lot and it seems to be working okay. I've only run into one other problem. I tested this on a large file (Alice in Wonderland text file) and the output file is almost the whole thing, but cuts off the last two paragraphs or so. My theory is that the last buffer would be those two paragraphs but isn't writing out to the file, maybe because the buffer size isn't PAGESIZE in size? I hope that makes sense. Can anyone see what would cause that bug in my code?

Comment: @medalib: although it isn't stated in the question, there's a strong chance that the `err_sys()` function is a 'no return' function that reports the message given as its argument plus the system error (as if by `perror()`) and then exits.  But you're right — if `err_sys()` can return, then the code needs to take more evasive action.

Comment: err_sys() is from apue.h if you are familiar with it. I'm pretty sure all errors that would be passed to err_sys from read() and write() are non-recoverable, at least that I've seen so far. It has a built-in perror/errno emulator, so it exits automatically

Comment: Regarding your "Alice" comment — see my updated answer.  Roughly: delete those `lseek()` calls; I know not what they do, but I'm sure they're not useful to you.

Comment: Did the trick. Thanks for all your help Jonathan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Transcribing comments into an answer.*</sup>

You need to capture the return value from `read()` — you're ignoring it and testing whether the file descriptor is 0 or negative after the `read()`.

> So if I did something like `int bytesRead` then tested for `if (bytesRead == 0)` instead of `if (fdRead == 0)`, then that should solve my problem?

Yes, you need something like:

```
int nbytes = read(fdRead, buf, size);
if (nbytes <= 0) break;
```

You should use the positive `nbytes` in the `write()` call; you might not get all size bytes filled by the `read()`.

Testing the file descriptor after the read is wrong (it won't have changed under normal circumstances), and ignoring the value returned by `read()` is wrong, and not using the value returned by `read()` in the call to `write()` is wrong.

> OK so it should be `write(fdWrite, buf, nbytes)`?

Yes, it should be

```
int obytes;
if ((obytes = write(fdWrite, buf, nbytes)) != nbytes)
{
   …oops — short write …
}
```

You get to decide what's the appropriate response to a short write (a positive value, but not the number of bytes you expected to write). If you're writing to a socket, it might be appropriate to try writing the unwritten section of the data again (that's why `obytes` is used to capture the number of bytes successfully written). If you're writing to a disk file, it probably means there's no space left, so there's no point (little point) in trying again.   If `obytes` is negative, you've had a write error; there is usually little point in trying to continue.

> This all has helped out a lot and it seems to be working okay. I've only run into one other problem. I tested this on a large file (Alice in Wonderland text file) and the output file is almost the whole thing, but cuts off the last two paragraphs or so. …

You need to review why you have the `lseek()` operations in the code.  Neither of them should be necessary, and both are dubious.  I think the `lseek()` on `fdRead()` means you miss chunks of text of `size` bytes each; I think the `lseek()` on `fdWrite()` means you insert `size` null bytes into the output file.

Answer (score 0):

```
            /*Here's the code which may help for that.i havemodified in it for your need.*/

        int fdRead = open(inputFile,                                             O_RDONLY);
        int Ret_Val;    
        if (fdRead == -1)
        err_sys("Error reading input file'%s',check spelling?\n", 
        inputFile );
        int fdWrite = open(outputFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT 
       | O_TRUNC, 0644); //overwrites file if it exists
        if (fdWrite == -1)
        err_sys("Error creating output file '%s'\n", outputFile);
        while (1) {
        Ret_Val=read(fdRead, buf, size);
        if (Ret_Val == 0)
            break;
        if (Ret_Val == -1)
        err_sys("Error reading from input file'%s'\n",inputFile);
        lseek(fdRead, size, SEEK_CUR);
        if (Ret_Val == -1)
            err_sys("Error reading from input file'%s'\n",             
        inputFile );
        Ret_Val=write(fdWrite, buf, size);
        if (Ret_Val == -1)
        err_sys("Error writing to output file'%s'\n",outputFile);
        lseek(fdWrite, size, SEEK_CUR);
        if (Ret_Val == -1)
        err_sys("Error writing to output file'%s'\n",outputFile);
        memset(buf, '\0', size);
        }
        close(fdRead);
        close(fdWrite);
```

Comment: I am new for stackoverflow please forgive me of the intending of above code.